# SSH versus FTP: Push local files to a server via Terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, ftp, terminal

I am a junior front-end developer and I am working on my process using command line. I would like to push my local changes to my server without having to use an FTP client like Filezilla. I am manually dragging and dropping files using the client and would like to learn how developers perform this process. I am building a static site using SiteLeaf on a Mac. Thanks in advance for help with this workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target has SSH installed you can use SCP:

```
$ scp -r your_remote_user@remote_address:/path/to/save/dir /local/dir/to/transfer
```

This can also be used to transfer single files: just remove the `-r` (recursive) option and specify files path instead of directories.

Comment: Hi Salem. Thanks. I will look into this SCP with my hosting provider.

Comment: Also you may check if Finder let's you mount a SSH remote location. I have never tried it, but in Linux this works fairly well.